# publishing events to pubnub blocks from javascript client

Tags: block, pubnub

I wanted to try out pubnub BLOCKS with a very contrived example. 
Essentially, I'm publishing a simple message from a client (using javascript sdk) to see if the BLOCK that I've set (or i "think" i've set) to that respective channel is listening...contrived example is failing thus far...

**Steps**

1. Create an APP in pubnub to generate credentials.
2. Included pubnub SDK in simple HTML file, initialized Pubnub, set event listener, and publish/subscribe methods. Set channel to 'hello-world' 
   2a. Published/Subscribed to messages successfully from different browser windows with .
3. Went to pubnub debug console and set channel as 'hello-world' to see if messages from 'hello-world' channel would be broadcast and they were not.
4. From the client, I console logged the object that is returned from messages and the channel is appearing as 'hello-world'..so this left me wondering, why aren't i seeing the messages registered in the pubnub debug console in the same hello-world channel ?

Particularly, my question is: how can i send messages to a pubnub BLOCK from a pubnub CLIENT and send messages from a pubnub BLOCK to a pubnub CLIENT ? or in other words, pub/sub a BLOCK with a CLIENT using the Javascript SDK ?

The simple.js for hello-world example code:

```
(function(){
  var pubnub = new PubNub({ publishKey : 'p-key', subscribeKey : 's-key' });
  function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
  var box = $('box'), input = $('input'), channel = 'hello-world';
  pubnub.addListener({
      message: function(obj) {
          box.innerHTML = (''+obj.message).replace( /[<>]/g, '' ) + '<br>' + box.innerHTML
      }});
  pubnub.subscribe({channels:[channel]});
  input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      if ((e.keyCode || e.charCode) === 13) {
        pubnub.publish({channel : channel,message : input.value,x : (input.value='')});
    }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Publishing Messages and Events to PubNub BLOCKS from JavaScript

I've created an example below which sends messages to PubNub.
You can [register a BLOCK](https://admin.pubnub.com/#/blocks/209/import) on the `hello-world` channel to catch the message.

1. [Register a BLOCK on PubNub](https://admin.pubnub.com/#/blocks/209/import).  Make sure to start/deploy the block.
2. Update the `publishKey` and `subscribeKey` in the example below.
3. Run the example below.

```js
(()=>{

    'use strict';
 
    // Initialize PubNub Socket SDK
    const pubnub = new PubNub({ 
        publishKey   : 'demo'
    ,   subscribeKey : 'demo'
    });

    // GUI Elements
    const box     = $('#messages')
    ,     input   = $('#message')
    ,     submit  = $('#submit')
    ,     channel = 'hello-world';

    // Open Socket to Channels
    pubnub.subscribe({ channels : [channel] });

    // When Messages Arrive
    pubnub.addListener({ message: obj => receive_chat(obj) });

    // When user sends chat
    submit.click( event => send_chat(input.val()) );
    input.keyup( event => {
        if ((event.keyCode || event.charCode) === 13)
            return send_chat(input.val());
    });

    // Draw Chat Messages on Screen
    function receive_chat(obj) {
        box.html((''+obj.message).replace( /[<>]/g, '' )+'<br>'+box.html());
    }

    // Send Chat Message
    function send_chat(message) {
        console.log(input.val());
        pubnub.publish({ channel : channel, message : message });
        input.val('');
        return false;
    }


})();
```

```css
div, input { font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans",Geneva,Arial,sans-serif; }
input { padding: 10px; margin: 10px;  }
input[type=submit] { width: 100px; line-height: 100px; font-size: 20px;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.4.3.min.js"></script>

<input id="message" placeholder="type your message">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Comment: oh lordy lord...I had set channel as hello_world in debug console and as hello-world in client, updated the channel spelling to match and is totally working now...super simple. late night misspelling mistake :/ thanks again  :) !

Comment: lol, totally understandable.  I'll try to make a runnable demo here as well.  Will update shortly.